# Session with Session-State=SQLServer getting expired on Production

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, session

I am working on Asp.net Web Application. I am facing an issue of session getting expired on production environment only, same is working fine on local.

I have set the **Session-State** to **SQLServer** in web.config, which means AppPool restart,changes in dll and config files shouldn't affect the session value.

But I couldn't figure out what is causing the session expiration.

Please suggest me,if there are any specific scenarios where session might get expired with **Session-State** to **SQLServer**

Comment: AppPool restart doesn't affect sessions???

Comment: What is the exact symptom you are experiencing? What exactly do you observe when you are talking about `session expiration`? What else have you checked during your debugging? Does the session state cookie get written correctly to the clients? What is the error the client experiences? What errors did you record on the server?

Comment: Could you give more details, like: does it expire by timeout? same timeout ever? are you running you app in a web garden?

Comment: @Igor: I am storing an object in a Session Variable. When I look into the logs, it reads **Object reference not set to instance of object** exactly at the line where I try to read session values. From this message, I came to conclusion that session is getting expired

Comment: @RicardoPontual: I have set timeout to 480 (8 hours). But the client is experiencing the issue randomly in interval of few mins (10-15 mins). I am running the app in Web farm

Comment: `exactly at the line where I try to read session values` <- can you provide a code snippet of this? Are you sure the value had been set before? It could be a logic error as well where or even a race condition issue, it depends on your code.

Comment: yeah I am sure the value had been set, because I have debugged it thoroughly at local